# File upload size issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting error on file upload in asp.net and the file size is 780kb but it is uploading 147 bytes successfully [image: enter code here]

i did set this in web.config file but still getting error any idea why?

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="1000000" executionTimeout="360"/>
    <!--<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="360"/>-->
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Just fyi, `maxRequestLength` is in KB, so your value of `1000000` is 1 Gigabyte.  I would recommend something smaller.

Comment: what is the content of the file with the size 780kb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be related to the file size - you would get a different error code. HTTP 400 usually indicates some problem in the request header. Do a [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) capture of the transaction to see what is actually being sent.

Answer (score 0):

There could be another web.config on AdminPanel level that overrides the site level setting.

Another option: upload could be done with Base64 encoding that makes data about 1.4 times bigger than file size (+ headers of the request). Make sure to set restriction accordingly.

Comment: I am developing this solution by myself and sure there is not anyother web.config file

Comment: If it is send using base64 then which one format is used for uploading?

Comment: Content-Transfer-Encoding:Base64. Use Fiddler or any other HTTP watcher to see how upload is done. See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html for official spec.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code as follows in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="600000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```